# Pencil and Pencil Project Package Naming Conflict

Tags: package-management

I have installaed Pencil 2d animation software. which you can see at http://www.pencil-animation.org/

and I want to install the Pencil Project wireframing app which is totally different. I want to know how to install the application without naming conflict?

As the previous name directory in usr/share is used by pencil animation, I can't install the pencil wireframing at the same time, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This issue still remains in Ubuntu 14.04 though it would appear that the pencil 2D animation may have changed the package name - see https://www.pencil2d.org/

Edit: It appears the naming conflict was [resolved](https://github.com/pencil2d/pencil/issues/580) on Dec 8, 2016. Detail is [here.](https://anonscm.debian.org/git/collab-maint/pencil2d.git/tree/debian/pencil2d.install)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't looked at the source for either of these, but if they allow specifying an install prefix (usually something like `./configure --prefix /opt/pencil-2d`) then you could install them in a way that avoids them conflicting.

However, this is likely to be a problem that other people run into too, and it really should be fixed at the root. Pencil is clearly too generic a name. Ideally we should persuade one or both of the projects to use a less generic name. This is something that comes up [every](http://www.mail-archive.com/info-gnu@gnu.org/msg00450.html) [now](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.announce/1710) [and](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.general/176836/focus=176884) [then](http://bugs.debian.org/665851), and the best long-term solution is upstream renaming.

If these were packaged for Debian/Ubuntu, they'd have to be modified to have different names (there can only be one `/usr/bin/pencil`), and store their data in different places. Other distributions would probably rename them differently, and then we end up with a situation where the applications behave differently on different distributions. This makes it harder for the upstreams to support their users.

So, it sounds like you need to talk to both of them, and get them to come up with less generic names. I suggest filing bugs with both, saying that the can't be co-installed with the other project. If the projects don't have a bug-tracker, mail their development mailing list / contact the authors however they like being contacted.